# Spark read files recursively from all sub folders with same name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have a process that is pushing bunch of data to the Blob store every hour and creating the following folder structure inside my storage container as below:
`/year=16/Month=03/Day=17/Hour=16/mydata.csv
/year=16/Month=03/Day=17/Hour=17/mydata.csv`

and so on

form inside my Spark context I want to access all the `mydata.csv` and process them. I figured out that I needed to set the `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")` so that we can use recursive search like below:

`val csvFile2 = sc.textFile("wasb://mycontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/*/*/*/mydata.csv")`

but when I execute the following command to see how many files I have received, it gives me some really large number like below

`csvFile2.count
res41: Long = 106715282`

ideally it should be returning me 24*16=384, also i verified on the container, it only has 384 `mydata.csv` files, but for some reasons i see it returns 106715282.

can someone please help me understand where I went wrong?

Regards
Kiran

Comment: `csvFile2.count` doesn't return the file count, it returns the _record_ count, that's why you see a large number...

Comment: @TzachZohar: Does this mean its the number of lines it has read totally from all these files. what do you mean by record here?

Comment: Yes, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#count() and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#textFile(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: @TzachZohar: OK that makes sense thanks. Any way to find the total number of files read?

Comment: `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles` would load each file to a single record, and then count _would_ be the number of files, but you don't want to do that - it would create huge records that may crash your job... The only alternative I can think of is performing a separate lookup using HDFS APIs (not Spark) before loading the data with Spark.

Comment: @TzachZohar I have one last query on this, what happens when a new file arrives, will this `csvFile2` automatically pick it up when i do count on it, or do I need to create a new variable? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to create a new one, assuming this one was already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`SparkContext` has two similar methods: `textFile` and `wholeTextFiles`.

`textFile` loads each *line* of each file as a record in the RDD. So `count()` will return the total number of lines across all of the files (which in most cases, such as yours, will be a large number).

`wholeTextFiles` loads each *entire file* as a record in the RDD. So `count()` will return the total number of files (384 in your case).